# Swift naming conventions for UI elements (labels, buttons, etc)

Tags: swift, coding-style, naming-conventions

Coming from the .NET world, I was used to naming my UI elements with the type prefix. Examples:

```
btnSend
lblName
etc...
```

The advantage is that in intellisense/autocomplete, the moment I start typing "btn..." I get to see the list of all my buttons.

However, I find that in Swift, the most common approach is to name UI elements with a type suffix instead:

```
sendButton
nameLabel
usersTableView
etc...
```

The problem is that I can't remember the names of all my buttons. When I start typing "butto...", I was hoping to see a list of all my buttons, but instead I'm seeing all the framework classes first, and I have to scroll down to see my stuff.

So, my question: is there a convention for naming UI elements? Does Apple recommend naming a button as `sendButton` instead of `btnSend` (or `buttonSend`)? Is there a setting in XCode that will allow me to see items I defined first in the autocomplete list?

Comment: I think it is more of readability, try actually saying the words out, "Send Button" sounds more natural than "Button Send" same goes for "Name Label" vs "Label Name"

Comment: Is there a way to make my names come on top of the autocomplete list?

Comment: By using it. AFAIK the list presents the most recently used auto complete option followed by the closest match in alphabetical order. So by using that autocomplete option you will push it to the top.

Comment: For sure, abbreviations like `btnSend` or `sendBtn` are strongly discouraged: they are hard to read, incompatible with spell checkers and incompatible with all Apple guidelines. Now, between `sendButton` and `buttonSend`, if you got a specific need for autocompletion, then feel free.

Comment: I always prefer to have the "top-most global" part of naming in the left side because it makes it really easy to have auto complete to find it and keep a standard on name

lets say you name it sendButton ... when you search for the button you dont know how to search for it cause each person in your team may pick a different name
it might be called "sendbutton" or "transferButton" or "forwardButton"... these results seem to mix up with stuff that has nothing to do with buttons like "Sendable"

so if you type "Button" you already see a list of possible buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can use any style as long as you are consistent with it throughout your application but still, if you want to go through the design guidelines you can check [swift-style-guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) by raywenderlich and [api-design-guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) from Apple.